# Pre-transform or transfer Raphael path

Tags: raphael

I have a path that undergoes some transforms. This creates a flicker between initial render (say Paper.text()) and the final transform. How can I either:

1. Perform all transformation prior to rendering so that it renders just once
   or
2. Create the transformed path in an off screen Paper then transfer the final path to my actual visible paper?

Not much in the docs that I can see but perhaps an undocumented trick?

My current solution is to make the text the same color as background but I would ideally like a more performant solution.

Comment: It's not clear if its fixed or dynamic, is it not possible to apply the final transform (e.g a sum of various transforms or whatever) when you create the element, eg paper.rect(1,2,3,4).transform('t10,10') or whatever ? Or you could set its opacity to 0, and then switch or animate to 1 when the final transform is applied ?

Comment: opacity is a step forward. I had tried `display: none` which didn't work. Chaining the transform still creates multiple renders. Due to the complexity of my paths and transforms I see a quick flicker.